# How to connect to elastic cache in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, redis, elastic-cache

I am looking for a way to connect the rails application to elastic cache for storing the cache. For testing purpose I try to test with redis-cli which is working fine. Is there any library or documentation available to connect to elastic cache. I already try to search but no luck

```
redis-cli -h primary-endpoint --tls -p 6379 -a "token"
```

I tried with redis-rails gem with the following code but it didn't work

```
REDIS_CONFIG = { 
    "url"=>"primary_endpoint",
     "port"=>6379
 }

@redis_token_store ||= Redis.new(REDIS_CONFIG)


@redis_token_store.set(1, "2")
```

I get the following error

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonblock': Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonbloc: Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block (IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable)
```

Also, not sure how to pass the token in the configuration

Comment: could you give us the error message you're getting from the `redis-gem`?

Comment: You have the Redis Ruby library configured incorrectly because it is clearly trying to connect to localhost instead of ElastiCache. See how it says `127.0.0.1` in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution if someone encountered the same he can take reference

The gem which I have used is redis-rails

```
Redis.new(url: "rediss://primary_endpoint:port_number", password: "")
```

Notice the "ss" in the **rediss** that is mandatory otherwise the connection will not get established from elastic cache

For [reference](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/771#issuecomment-411542148)

The authentication token(which is fetched from AWS Secret Manager) can be passed into the password